# How can I get the SYSTEM account's environment variables in my non-impersonated Custom Action?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I have a deferred custom action that I'm running at commit, and is set **not** to impersonate. Calling `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` in my action confirms that the current identity is for NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.

But when I use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` to get some input for my action, it's returning my normal logged-in user's values instead of those for SYSTEM:

```
var profilePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE");
// profilePath == "c:\users\[myname]", expecting "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile"
```

Why is this happening, and how can I get SYSTEM's environment? Thanks!

Comment: Can we ask what you are doing in this custom action? Messing with the SYSTEM's profile is **borderline malware behavior** - in my opinion (**no offence**). At the very least I would immediately test what security software does if you run this custom action "on their watch" - before spending any more time perfecting the action itself. My guess is that a leading security software (Kaspersky, McAfee, ESET, Trend Micro, Norton, Bitdefender, etc...) might actually block you trying to do this, with mysterious results. Trend Micro was particularly trigger happy during my testing a while back.

Comment: This is for a Windows Service that runs as SYSTEM. And I'm not setting anything, merely getting.

Comment: I never use commit custom actions, but I assume you have tried to make the custom action in question a regular, deferred mode custom action just for testing purposes? And I assume you know - [from the MSI documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367991.aspx) - that rollback and commit custom actions do not run when rollback is disabled? (it sounds like you are aware of this, just want to make sure). Bear with me on this one - just trying to give you some heads-ups without being an expert on commit actions. My 2 cents is that even reading here could set of security software?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. And yes, I do know. I'm sympathetic to the security-scanning implications, but I'll deal with them if/when they arise - my focus at this point is on properly deploying my runs-as-SYSTEM-Windows-Service based on SYSTEM's environment.

Comment: I was all ready to suggest reading the Environment registry key's values, but I don't think that will help your scenario. Can you move whatever you were really trying to do here into your app/service?

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts that might help.

Windows Installer uses impersonation a lot, but it won't do the equivalent of LoadUserProfile to load a user's profile (like an interactive logon does) because the process could be loading a new user profile at every custom action call, depending on whether it's impersonated or not. Running as the system account is just more impersonation and doesn't mean that the system account's profile is loaded.

As far as I know, you get this folder by having an access token for the system account, and then use the Win32 API GetUserProfileDirectory () or managed equivalent.

It may help if you describe the ultimate goal you're trying to accomplish. It's not clear if this is an [XY Problem or not](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I'm deploying a Windows Service that uses an SDK that relies on reading some of *its* configuration from a file in the user's profile directory. The SDK offers the ability to programmatically create the file in the user's profile but relies on the ambient USERPROFILE environment variable to pick the profile directory. The Windows Service runs as SYSTEM, but (as my question states) the Custom Action to produce the file doesn't get SYSTEM's environment variables, so the produced file doesn't end up in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6k3c7b0(v=vs.110).aspx) that facilitates the functionality:

```
public static string GetEnvironmentVariable(
    string variable,
    EnvironmentVariableTarget target
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but that doesn't work either. That overload looks in a different registry hive, and the environment variables in question aren't there.

Comment: Very sorry, should have paid more attention. If `USERPROFILE` or something involving `USERNAME` is what your after, why are you shocked that returns valid data? I guess you will need to enumerate the local accounts and derive their profile location.

Comment: NT Authority\SYSTEM also has valid USERPROFILE and USERNAME environment variables, so it's valid data, but from the wrong dataset.